# How Do I show hours, minutes and seconds in TimePicker or DatePicker at Windows Phone?

Tags: windows-phone-7, timepicker, elapsedtime, datapicker

I am doing a temporizer or elapsed time, but i want choose the time start with a timepicker or datetpicker, throught hours, minutes and seconds.

Please I need help!!! Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? Did you try the timepicker UI element? http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dpatra/timepicker-in-silverlight-4/

Comment: As the second screenshot http://www.windowsphone.com/es-es/store/app/stopwatch_timer/f9507895-0163-4c79-852e-0750f56200b6

Comment: Now, i found the solution, i used the TimespanPicker of Codin4fun. :)